# помогите в настройке Bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap

Использую стартовый шаблон БУТСТРАП к нему добавил уже все что можно и Js, jq, а он все равно работает не корректно!((
Навбар нормально не отображается, как то криво все, Карусель не прокручивается, я так понимаю где то ошибка именно с подключением и порядком скриптов!
посоветуйте и помогите мне разобраться, кто пользуется стартовым шаблоном, настроенным под норм работу, скиньте в комменты, буду очень благодарен!

```css
body{
 background: #f2f2f2;
 font-family: "Lato";
 font-weight: 300;
 color: #555;
 font-size: 14px;

 -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
 -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
 margin-top: 70px;
}

i {
font-family: fontawesome !important;
}

a{
 color: #f85c37;
}
a:hover, a:focus{
 color: #7b7b7b;
 text-decoration: none;
 outline: 0;
}

h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{
 font-family: "Raleway";
 font-weight: 300;
 color: #333;
}
p{
 line-height: 28px;
 margin-bottom: 25px;
}
.centered{
 text-align: center;
}
hr{
 display: block;
 height: 1px;
 border: 0;
 border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
 margin: 1em 0;
 padding: 0;
}
.navbar{
 font-weight: 800;
 font-size: 14px;
 padding-top: 15px;
 padding-bottom: 15px;
}
.navbar-inverse{
 background: #2d2d2d;
 border-color: #2d2d2d;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a{
background-color: #ff7878;
}

ul .navbar, .navbar-nav> li{
 margin-left: 90px;
}

#car{
 padding: 0;
}

#headerwrap{
 background: #cecece;
 margin-top: -10px;
 padding-top: 20px;
 text-align: center;
 background-attachment: relative;
 background-position: center center;
 min-height: 500px;
 width: 100%

 background-size: 100%;

 -webkit-background-size: cover;
 -moz-background-size: cover;
 -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
#headerwrap h1{
 margin-top: 100px;
 color: #990033;
 font-size: 70px;
 font-weight: 300;
 letter-spacing: 3px;
 text-shadow: 0px 5px 2px #330000;
}

#headerwrap h2{
 font-size: 40px;
 color: #FF6600;
 letter-spacing: 2px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 text-shadow: 0px 5px 2px #000;
}

.w{
 padding-top: 35px;
}

.w h4{
 font-size: 25px;
}
.tilt:hover{
 -webkit-transform: rotate(-10deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-10deg);
     -ms-transform: rotate(-10deg);
      -o-transform: rotate(-10deg);
         transform: rotate(-10deg);
}
#dg{
 background: #e0e0e0;
 padding-top: 70px;
 padding-bottom: 70px;
 text-align: center;
}
#dg h4{
 font-size: 40px;
 padding-top: 20px;
 text-shadow: 0px 3px 0px #000;
}

#lg{
 background: #DC143C;
 padding-bottom: 20px;
}
.fa-male,
.fa-users, 
.fa-user-times,
.fa-wheelchair-alt,
.fa-plane{
 font-size: 100px;
}
#lg> .centered{
 color: #696969;
 font-size: 38px;
 text-align: center;
 text-shadow: 2px 2px 0px #000;
 padding-top: 70px;
 padding-bottom: 60px;
}

#lg a{
 color: black;
}
#lg a:hover{
 color: #010;
}

#f{
 background: #2d2d2d;
 font-size: 35px;

}
#f a> img{
 height: 20%;
 margin-top: 40px;
}
#f a> img:hover{
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px red;
 transform: scale(0.9);
 border-radius: 50%;
 transition: box-shadow, transform;
 transition-duration: 0.25s, 0.70s;
 
}
.cont{
 background: url(IMG/batman_arkham.jpg) no-repeat;
 background-position: center center;
 background-attachment: relative;
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
 background-size: cover;
 min-height: 200px;
 max-height: 550px;
 padding-top: 30px;
 padding-bottom: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="fedCSS.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="fontawesome.min.css">
    <title>F.A</title>
  </head>
  <body>
     
      <div class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" >
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
              <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">F.<i class="fa fa-circle" style="font-size: 30px"></i>.A</a>
          </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse align-items-start justify-content-between">
              <ul class="navbar navbar-nav navbar-right ">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Главная</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"> Про Нас</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Наши проэкты</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Портфолио</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-bug" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>

<!--
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="third-slide" src="IMG/Twitter_7themes-su.jpg" alt="Third slide">
            <div class="container">
              <div class="carousel-caption text-right">
                <h1>Ваш зоголовок.</h1>
                <p>Ваш текст.</p>
                <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Browse gallery</a></p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
-->
     <div class="container-fluid" id="car">
        <div class="carousel slide" id="carouselIndicators" data-ride="carousel">

          <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li class="active" data-target="#carouselIndicators" data-slide-to="0"></li>
            <li class="active" data-target="#carouselIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            <li class="active" data-target="#carouselIndicators" data-slide-to="3"></li>
            <li class="active" data-target="#carouselIndicators" data-slide-to="4"></li>
          </ol>

          <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
              <img src="IMG/Opera_7themes-su.jpg" alt="" class="d-block w-100">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
              <img src="IMG/сетевых подключений_7themes-su.jpg" alt="" class="d-block w-100">
            </div> 
            <div class="carousel-item">
              <img src="IMG/HTML тег_7themes-su.jpg" alt="" class="d-block w-100">
            </div> 
            <div class="carousel-item">
              <img src="IMG/Twitter_7themes-su.jpg" alt="" class="d-block w-100">
            </div>
         
          </div>

          <a href="#carouselIndicators" class="carousel-control-prev" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true" ></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Prev</span>
              </a> 
              <a href="#carouselIndicators" class="carousel-control-next" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true" ></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
              </a>
        </div>
      </div>

        <div id="headerwrap">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="row centered">
              <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
                <h1>Bootstrap is awesome</h1>
                <h2>Сайты на бутстрап отличные!</h2>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="container w">
          <div class="row centered">
            <br><br>
              <div class="col-lg-4">
                <i class="fa fa-heart"></i>
                <h4>Дизайн</h4>
                <p>Диза́йн (от англ. design — проектировать, чертить, задумать, а также проект, план, рисунок) — деятельность по проектированию эстетических свойств промышленных изделий («художественное конструирование»), а также результат этой деятельности (например, в таких словосочетаниях, как «дизайн автомобиля»)</p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-4">
              <i class="fa fa-laptop"></i>
              <h4>Компьютеры</h4>
              <p>Компью́тер (англ. computer, МФА: [kəmˈpjuː.tə(ɹ)]— «вычислитель») — устройство или система, способная выполнять заданную, чётко определённую, изменяемую последовательность операций. </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
              <i class="fa fa-trophy"></i>
              <h4>Телефоны</h4>
              <p>Телефо́н (от др.-греч. τῆλε «далеко» + φωνή «голос», «звук») — аппарат для передачи и приёма звука (в основном — человеческой речи) на расстоянии. Современные телефоны осуществляют передачу посредством электрических сигналов</p>
            </div>
            <br><br>
          </div>
        </div>
        

          <div id="dg">
            <div class="container-fluid">
              <h4>New Gadgets</h4>
              <div class="row centered">
                <br><br>
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                  <div class="tilt">
                    <a href=""><img src="IMG/IPhone.png" alt="phone"></a>
                  </div>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg">Купить</button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                  <div class="tilt">
                    <a href=""><img src="IMG/IPhone.png" alt="phone"></a>
                  </div>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg">Купить</button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                  <div class="tilt">
                    <a href=""><img src="IMG/IPhone.png" alt="phone"></a>
                  </div>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg">Купить</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
                
          <div class="container wb">
            <div class="row centered">
              <br><br><br><br>
              <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
                <h4>Мы создаем сайты!</h4>
                <p>Сайт – лицо компании в Интернете. Благодаря ему, вы повысите узнаваемость бренда, торговой марки и найдете новых клиентов. Мы создаем сайты, которые будут работать на вас.</p>
                <br><br><br><br>
                <div class="col-lg-2"></div>
                <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset">
                  <img src="IMG/Lenovo-G50-80.jpg" alt="lenovo" class="img-responsive">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
    
            <br><br><br>

          <div id="lg">
            <h4 class="centered">Партнеры</h4>
            <div class="container">
              <div class="row centered">

                <div class="col-lg-3 col-offset-1">
                 <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-male" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-3">
                 <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-users" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                </div> 

                 <div class="col-lg-3">
                 <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-wheelchair-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                </div>

                 <div class="col-lg-3">
                 <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-plane" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="container-fluid cont">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9 col">
                  <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/?v=mvntgMuUPhU&list=PL3LQJkGQtzc51x2RpSNk3e3Ebh7rbKCkB&index=2" class="embed-responsive-item p-5  h-50" allowfullscreen ></iframe>
                </div> 
                <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9 col">
                  <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/?v=sssu2d1UqrE&index=1&list=PL3LQJkGQtzc51x2RpSNk3e3Ebh7rbKCkB" class="embed-responsive-item p-5 h-50" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                </div> 
                <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9 col">
                  <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/?v=GHYPsEDd_bs&list=PL3LQJkGQtzc51x2RpSNk3e3Ebh7rbKCkB&index=3" class="embed-responsive-item p-5 h-50" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                </div>
              </div>
          </div>


          <div id="f">
            <div class="container">
              <div class="row left">
                <a href="#" class="col-lg-1"><img src="IMG/social_icons/Social Icons by Dreamstale (12).png" alt=""></a>
                <a href="#" class="col-lg-1"><img src="IMG/social_icons/Social Icons by Dreamstale (6).png" alt=""></a>
                <a href="#" class="col-lg-1"><img src="IMG/social_icons/Social Icons by Dreamstale (12).png" alt=""></a>
                <a href="#" class="col-lg-1"><img src="IMG/social_icons/Social Icons by Dreamstale (15).png" alt=""></a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
         

    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

   <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!--Иконочный шрифт-->
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/solid.js" integrity="sha384-+Ga2s7YBbhOD6nie0DzrZpJes+b2K1xkpKxTFFcx59QmVPaSA8c7pycsNaFwUK6l" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/fontawesome.js" integrity="sha384-7ox8Q2yzO/uWircfojVuCQOZl+ZZBg2D2J5nkpLqzH1HY0C1dHlTKIbpRz/LG23c" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ты подключаешь Bootstrap 4 и тему для Bootstrap 3. [Отдельные темы были удалены из Bootstrap 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40428410/how-do-i-make-bootstrap-v4-look-like-v3).

Comment: бутстрап 4 подключаю, сейчас начал подключать через скачаный бутстрап, все отлично, но все же меня волнует вопрос почему через стартовый шаблон и подключеные мои скрипты код ломается?